# Displaying photo library images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, alassetslibrary

I am trying to display images from Photo Library in `UICollectionView` through `ALAssetsLibrary`  my codes runs fine , but I have some issues .

1. The quality of thumbnails are poor .
2. How can arrange collection view show 100 recent photos by ordering
   from

new to old .

here is my codes :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // collect the photos
    NSMutableArray *collector = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    ALAssetsLibrary *al = [ViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];
    [al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                      usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
     {
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
          {
              if (asset) {
                  [collector addObject:asset];
              }
          }];

         self.photos = collector;
     }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) { NSLog(@"error");}];


}



-(void)setPhotos:(NSArray *)photos {
    if (_photos != photos) {
        _photos = photos;
        [_collectionView reloadData];
    }
}


+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library;
}



- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return _photos.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *collectionImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    ALAsset *asset = [self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];
    img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    [collectionImageView setImage:img];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: use [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate] to sort the photos from new to old.

Comment: y r u converting the img to cgi img ? Could it be the possible reason for the poor quality ?

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran Where should I put this code ? view did load? would please be more specific ? thanks

Comment: @Mc.Lover.I added the answer. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to sort the photos.

```
self.photos = [collector sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ALAsset *first, ALAsset *second) {

   NSDate * date1 = [first valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
    NSDate * date2 = [second valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks , it crashes due to `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ALAsset 0x7f9bb3c33fa0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ALAssetPropertyDate.'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: @Mc.Lover I have edited the answer. please take a look.

Comment: Nothing changed ! it runs fine but still I have see old image  I have to scroll down to see new ones

Comment: try [date2 compare:date1]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date of an image saved in the library by:

```
  NSDate * date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
```

You can compare this date with today's date, and store it an array, and do the same for the 100 Images.

And to your other question,

The thumbnail img you get from asset is of different size depends on iOS. In iOS 9 it is of 75x75 and in iOS 8, it is of 150x150.

You can try this:

```
      [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]
```

Comment: Also may I knw y are you doing the conversion of imgWithCGi twice ?